# Unsupported media type ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

On the front-end i use Angular to collect som data from the form and send it to my server-side controllers. As the image shows below, i get the data ($scope.newData) on my controller and service, but when it reaches the server, i get the following error: "Unsupported media type" and my newData is empty.

[image: Website console]

My controller:

```
// Create new salesman
  $scope.addSalesman = function (newData) {
    console.log("Controller");
    console.log($scope.newData);
    myService.addNewSalesman($scope.newData).then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }, function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };
```

My service:

```
addNewSalesman: function (newData) {
            console.log("service");
            console.log(newData)
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/Salesman',
                headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
            }, newData).then(function (res) {
                deferred.resolve(res.data);
            }, function (res) {
                deferred.reject(res);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

My Salesman model:

```
public class Salesman
    {
        public int SalesmanID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int Postal { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
```

My server-side controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SalesmanController : Controller
{

    private readonly DataAccess _DataAccess;

    public SalesmanController() 
    { 
        _DataAccess = new DataAccess(); 
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostSalesman([FromBody] Salesman newData)
    {
        return Ok(newData); 
    }
```

Comment: Can you can see that your angular service is sending the correct headers and sending a JSON payload?

Comment: If you inspect element and check under the network. This is where i could see it.

Comment: I'm asking you to show us the request payload + headers :)

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/H0hGE

Not sure if you want to see my service, but here it is. I had no problem with the post, but when i had to delete, the headers had to be added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The header you are sending is wrong. You are sending `Content-Type: application/json`, but you have to send `Accept: application/json`.

`Content-Type: application/json` is what the server must send to the client and the client must send `Accept` to tell the server which type of response it accepts.

```
addNewSalesman: function (newData) {
        console.log("service");
        console.log(newData)
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/Salesman',
            headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }
        }, newData).then(function (res) {
            deferred.resolve(res.data);
        }, function (res) {
            deferred.reject(res);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Should do it. Also see "[Content negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation)" on MDN.

Comment: That's odd as json is registered out of the box with mvc and only xml needs to be registered separately. Did you try to remove the headers section all along? Angular should be able to put sane default values there

Comment: It's funny because now it actually works without any headers or accept at all. Wierd.

Answer (score 16):

Just replace `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]` in your controller.

Answer (score 8):

This is a CORS issue.

During development it's safe to accept all http request methods from all origins. Add the following to your startup.cs:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        //Accept All HTTP Request Methods from all origins
        app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod());

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors) for more details about CORS.

Comment: In that case what is the solution for production environments?

Comment: In prod env you should specify a cross-origin policy when adding the CORS middleware using the CorsPolicyBuilder class. Your CORS policies are practically a "white list" of origins that are allowed into your API. Read more here: [link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#set-the-allowed-origins

Answer (score 0):

I had this where the receiving controller method was expecting a [FromBody] argument, but the calling service omitted the parameter.
At a guess under the hood, a controller method that expects a (serialised) parameter would expect the request content type (MIME) to be application/json - but the HttpClient calling POST/PUT without a parameter does not pass this (maybe just   text/html) - and hence we get 415 'Unsupported Media Type'.